# GET your dubs together

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, counting

On 4chan, a popular game is get. Every post on the site gets a sequential post ID. Since you can't influence or determine them, people try to guess (at least a part of) their own post number, usually the first few digits. Another version of the game is called dubs, and it's goal is to get repeating digits at the end of the number (i.e 1234555).

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program that takes a post id as input (standard integer, you can assume below 2^32), and returns how many repeating digits are on the end.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are **disallowed**.
- The program can be a function, full program, REPL command, whatever works, really, as long as no external uncounted code/arguments are needed to run it.
- Input can come from STDIN, function arguments, command line argument, file, whatever suits you.

## Test Cases

```
Input: 14892093
Output: 1

Input: 12344444
Output: 5

Input: 112311
Output: 2

Input: 888888
Output: 6

Input: 135866667 //Post number I got on /pol/ few days ago, rip
Output: 1
```

Comment: Are we allowed to take input as string?

Comment: @DeadPossum I would assume that's allowed, since you get a string anyway if you read the input from STDIN, command-line argument or file (which are all admissible input methods).

Comment: Can we assume that the input will be greater than 0?

Comment: @MartinEnder Yes

Comment: Upvote for the dubs game! Check'em!

Comment: @sagiksp That [goes against our default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7634/45941). Is that really your intent?

Comment: @Mego Nevermind you can use it all

Comment: Could someone make a solution that actually uses 4chan and some URL-related feature?

Comment: @ckjbgames What would it be, the user gets a url and has to regex the number out first? I'm thinking maybe a comment finder by ID would work (Looks through all threads with sequential id to find a specific id comment, because you can't index by comment in the 4chan api), but for this challeange it just won't work.

Comment: Disappointed: The question ID on SE does not have dubs.

Comment: @NumLock That would have been so perfect :D

Answer (score 21):

### Mathematica, 29 bytes

How about an arithmetic solution?

```
IntegerExponent[9#+#~Mod~10]&
```

I'm very pleased to see that this beats the straight-forward Mathematica approach.

#### Explanation

The code itself computes **9*n + n%10** and then finds the largest power of **10** that divides the input, or in other words, counts the trailing zeros. We need to show if **n** ends in **k** repeated digits, that **9*n + n%10** has **k** trailing zeros.

Rep-digits are most easily expressed mathematically by dividing a number like **99999** (which is **10<sup>5</sup>-1**) by **9** and then multiplying by the repeated digit. So we can write **n = m*10<sup>k</sup> + d*(10<sup>k</sup>-1)/9**, where **m ≢ d (mod 10)**, to ensure that **n** doesn't end in *more* than **k** repeated digits. Note that **d = n%10**.

Let's plug that into our formula **9*n + n%10**. We get **9*m*10<sup>k</sup> + d*(10<sup>k</sup>-1) + d**. The **d** at the end is cancelled, so we're left with: **9*m*10<sup>k</sup> + d*10<sup>k</sup> = (9*m + d)*10<sup>k</sup>**. But **9 ≡ -1 (mod 10)**, so **9*m + d ≡ d - m (mod 10)**. But we've asserted that **m ≢ d (mod 10)** and hence **d - m ≢ 0 (mod 10)**.

In other words, we've shown that **9*m + d** is not divisible by **10** and therefore, the largest power of **10** that divides **9*n + n%10 = (9*m + d)*10<sup>k</sup>** is **k**, the number of trailing repeated digits.

As a bonus, this solution prints the correct result, `∞`, for input `0`.

Comment: It's times like this that I wish this site supported MathJax; bold formulae are not as nice as typeset ones. It's nice that you took the time to write the exponents superscript though.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I used to use code formatting, but I've found that bold (which is usually used by Dennis) is a bit more readable than that. But agreed, it's not as nice as MathJax.

Answer (score 15):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 9 bytes

```
&`(.)\1*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivlqChpxljqKXy/7@hiYWlkYGlMZehkbEJEHAZAhmGhlwWYMBlaGxqYQYE5goA)

Counts the number of overlapping matches of `(.)\1*$` which is a regex that matches a suffix of identical characters.

Comment: This must be a meme: you and your regex

Comment: I need to learn all of these modifiers - I would have just gone for `(.)(?=\1*$)`.

Comment: @DownChristopher he **literally** made a regex-based language, this goes beyond meme material c:

Comment: @Neil If it's any consolation, my first attempt was `(?=(.)\1*$)` (so basically the same as yours).

Comment: Yes it is, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ẹḅtl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9w186HO1pLcv7/NzQyNgGB/1EA)

#### Explanation

```
ẹ       Elements: split to a list of digits
 ḅ      Blocks: group consecutive equal digits into lists
  t     Tail: take the last list
   l    Length: Output is the length of that last list
```

If `ḅ` worked directly on integers (and I'm not sure why I didn't implement it so that it does), this would only be 3 bytes as the `ẹ` would not be needed.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> 41 bytes

```python
lambda s:len(`s`)-len(`s`.rstrip(`s%10`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbJWTmqeRUJygqQtl6BUVlxRlFgCZqoYGCZqa/wuKMvNKFNI0MvMKSks0gAKGhkbGhoYA)

#### 36 bytes - For a more flexible input

```python
lambda s:len(s)-len(s.rstrip(s[-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbJWTmqdRrKkLpvSKikuKMgs0iqN1DWM1Nf8XFGXmlSikaWTmFZSWaAAF1A0NjYwNDdUB)

Comment: Wow. I gotta learn builtins more attentively. +1

Comment: @DeadPossum `dir(object)` is our friend c:

Comment: BTW we are not allowed to take string as input. "If your method of input automatically returns strings then sure, but you cannot assume that the input will be provided as strings." :C

Comment: @DeadPossum I think that the author changed his mind about that. The comment seems to have been deleted.

Answer (score 8):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>55</s> <s>52</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```js
a=>a.match`(.)\\1*$`[0].length
```

- Saved **19** bytes thanks to @MartinEnder by replacing the regex
- Saved **2** bytes thanks to @user81655 using tagged templates literals

---

Using a regex to match the last group of the last digit

*Note: First time posting. Do not hesitate to make remarks.*

```js
f=a=>a.match`(.)\\1*$`[0].length


console.log(f("14892093"));//1
console.log(f("12344444"));//5
console.log(f("112311"));//2
console.log(f("888888"));//6
console.log(f("135866667 "));//1
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can save a lot of bytes by using a backreference instead of filling in the repeated character manually: `/(.)\1*$/`

Comment: Also, unnamed functions are completely fine (unless you need the name for recursive calls for example), so you can save two bytes on the `f=`.

Comment: Good job! This for sure passes review but this could be golfed

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks ! I still have to learn how to golf

Comment: @DownChristopher Thanks ! I will try to do better next time

Comment: @Weedoze Yeah golfing is really hard but good job

Comment: Anonymous functions are allowed, so you can remove the `f=` from your byte count. :) Also, another trick you could use is [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals). `match` passes its first argument into `RegExp(arg)`, so you can pass a string and it will turn into a `RegExp` object. Knowing this, you could call it like `match\`(.)\\1*$\`` for one less byte.

Comment: @user81655 Thanks ! I am still learning the tricks of golfing

Comment: @Weedoze Make sure to explicitly say if it's Javascript ES6 or not (for clarity).

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>62</s> <s>56</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Steadybox!*

```c
j,k;f(n){for(k=j=n%10;j==n%10;n/=10,k++);k-=j;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@lk22dppGnWZ2WX6SRbZtlm6dqaGCdZQuh8/RtDQ10srW1Na2zdW2zrGv/5yZm5mloVhcUZeaVpGkoqabE5KFiJR2uNA1DEwtLIwNLY00wx8jYBAQgHCDP0BDMtAADiKixqYUZEJhragLtAAA)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9LJ9s6TSNPszotv0gj2zbLNk/V0MA6yxZCZ2tra@bp24JYurZZ1rX/cxMz8zQ0qwuKMvNK0jSUVFNi8lCxkg5XmoahiYWlkYGlsSaYY2RsAgIQDpBnaAhmWoABRNTY1MIMCMw1NYF2AAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 22 bytes

21 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
/(.)\1*$/;$_=length$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAtyPmvr6GnGWOopaJvrRJvm5Oal16SoaL2/79nXkFpiZWCoYmFpZGBpTGXoZGxCQhwGQJZhoZcFmDAZWhsamEGBOYA)

`/(.)\1*$/` gets the last identical numbers, and then `$_=length$&` assigns its length to `$_`, which is implicitly printed thanks to `-p` flag.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <strike>47</strike> <strike>45</strike> 40 bytes

```
while($argn[-++$i]==$argn[-1]);echo$i-1;
```

Run with `echo <n> | php -nR '<code>`

seems a loop is still smaller than my first answer. simply count the chars that are equal to the last. This uses negative string offsets of *PHP 7.1*.

*-5 bytes* by Titus. Thanks !

---

Old answer:

```
<?=strlen($a=$argv[1])-strlen(chop($a,$a[-1]));
```

removes from the right every character matching the rightmost character and calculates the difference in the length.

Comment: `-R` and `$argn` could save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>38</s> 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:0<n%100%11or-~f(n/10)
```

*Thanks to @xnor for saving 6 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HczBCsIwEIThsz7FXJY2kOJuUzUp6rtUQqCgWwmeffW4@p3@uUwr18fyvOcFOvNFSZhJZKvDp/R6EHatbBWKVSFTTCOn4CFjmH6sLEU84p/tcIwnc573u1dd9Y2OUsZwA@UOhF497Ni59gU)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
.¡¤g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@693aOGhJen//xsaGZsAAQA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/K93aOGhJen/K5UO77dSOLxfSee/oYmFpZGBpTGXoZGxCRBwGQIZhoZcFmDAZWhsamEGBOYA)

**Explanation**

```
.¡    # group consecutive equal elements in input
  ¤   # get the last group
   g  # push its length
```

Answer (score 6):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
re`W=0=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#K/TTr7YKsv4flJoQbmtg@z82r1b/v6GJhaWRgaUxl6GRsQkQcBkCGYaGXBZgwGVobGphBgTmAA)

#### Explanation

```
r   e# Read input.
e`  e# Run-length encode.
W=  e# Get last run.
0=  e# Get length.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
DŒgṪL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9ydFL6w52rfP7//29oZGwCBAA)

**Explanation**

```
D      # convert from integer to decimal   
 Œg    # group runs of equal elements
   Ṫ   # tail
    L  # length
```

Answer (score 6):

## Cubix, <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
)uO)ABq-!wpUp)W.@;;
```

## Note

- Actually counts how many of the same characters are at the end of the input, so this works for really big integers and really long strings as well (as long as the amount of same characters at the end is smaller than the maximum precision of JavaScript (around 15 digits in base-10).
- Input goes in the input field, output is printed to the output field

[Try it here](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=KXVPKUFCcS0hd3BVcClXLkA7Ow==&input=MTM1ODY2NjY3)

## Explanation

First, let's expand the cube

```
    ) u
    O )
A B q - ! w p U
p ) W . @ ; ; .
    . .
    . .
```

The steps in the execution can be split up in three phases:

1. Parse input
2. Compare characters
3. Print result

### Phase 1: Input

The first two characters that are executed are `A` and `B`. `A` reads all input and pushes it as character codes to the stack. Note that this is done in reverse, the first character ends up on top of the stack, the last character almost at the bottom. At the very bottom, `-1` (`EOF`) is placed, which will be used as a counter for the amount of consecutive characters at the end of the string. Since we need the top of the stack to contain the last two characters, we reverse the stack, before entering the loop. Note that the top part of the stack now looks like: `..., C[n-1], C[n], -1`.

The IP's place on the cube is where the `E` is, and it's pointing right. All instructions that have not yet been executed, were replaced by no-ops (full stops).

```
    . .
    . .
A B E . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

### Phase 2: Character comparison

The stack is `..., C[a-1], C[a], counter`, where `counter` is the counter to increment when the two characters to check (`C[a]` and `C[a-1]`) are equal. The IP first enters this loop at the `S` character, moving right. The `E` character is the position where the IP will end up (pointing right) when `C[a]` and `C[a-1]` do not have the same value, which means that subtracting `C[a]` from `C[a-1]` does not yield `0`, in which case the instruction following the `!` will be skipped (which is a `w`).

```
    . .
    . .
. S q - ! w E .
p ) W . . ; ; .
    . .
    . .
```

Here are the instructions that are executed during a full loop:

```
q-!;;p) # Explanation
q       # Push counter to the bottom of the stack
        #     Stack (counter, ..., C[a-1], C[a])
 -      # Subtract C[a] from C[a-1], which is 0 if both are equal
        #     Stack (counter, ..., C[a-1], C[a], C[a-1]-C[a])
  !     # Leave the loop if C[a-1]-C[a] does not equal 0
   ;;   # Remove result of subtraction and C[a] from stack
        #     Stack (counter, ..., C[a-1])
     p  # Move the bottom of the stack to the top
        #     Stack (..., C[a-1], counter)
      ) # Increment the counter
        #     Stack (..., C[a-1], counter + 1)
```

And then it loops around.

### Phase 3: Print result

Since we left the loop early, the stack looks like this: `counter, ..., C[a-1]-C[a]`. It's easy to print the counter, but we have to increment the counter once because we didn't do it in the last iteration of the loop, and once more because we started counting at `-1` instead of `0`. The path on the cube looks like this, starting at `S`, pointing right. The two no-ops that are executed by the IP are replaced by arrows that point in the direction of the IP.

```
    ) u
    O )
. B . . . S p U
. ) . . @ . . .
    > >
    . .
```

The instructions are executed in the following order. Note that the `B)` instructions at the end change the stack, but don't affect the program, since we are about to terminate it, and we do not use the stack anymore.

```
p))OB)@ # Explanation
p       # Pull the counter to the top
        #     Stack: (..., counter)
 ))     # Add two
        #     Stack: (..., counter + 2)
   O    # Output as number
    B)  # Reverse the stack and increment the top
      @ # End the program
```

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```c
f(x){x=x%100%11?1:-~f(x/10);}
```

This is a port of [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114241/12012).

This work with gcc, but the lack of a `return` statement is undefined behavior.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#HYzRCoJAFESfd79iEBZ2baW9aqaJ9SHVQ6CSUEuEkCD263a38zQzzMza68nMUzMpck4RneiQfDnbkjP1sg5@xPM2eG3kLEVw47m4osFMeVmlrsosKM3yACuWRBblH/bZriyY/WIRe16NtZTicx8eHXTsjRTi9ebTXkeqapEcodqLj0LZog8NY@GxaUC1XNYf)

Comment: I'm confused, how come you neither pass a pointer, and change the value at the location, or just return the value. This looks like it just changes the local copy, which would make the function unusable, but this works on TIO. You also add 1 to n in the footer, rather then sizeof(int), wouldn't that move it 1 byte forwards, rather than the full width of an int? Clearly there are some tricks I could learn here, and I could probably use the first one in my own answer.

Comment: All the `return` statement does is storing the return value in EAX. With gcc, assigning it to a variable happens to do the same thing. As for the pointer arithmetic, when you add 1 to an int pointer, it moves to the next int, not the next byte.

Comment: Are there cases (when using ints) when it would be better to return, it seems like in the worst case you would make a new int, and assign that.

Comment: @Bijan C compilers always align direct memory access to the size of an atom of the primitive in question -- i don't remember if it's in the standard, though

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 51 bytes

Takes integer as input. [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#y7GN@Z@TmJuUkqgQbBVdYWubEJwQrWsYm5ZfpFChkJkH4lpZAQW01evUY/Uy81JSKzQMNP8XFGXmlSjkaBgaGWtyIXGMkbggzn8A)

```
lambda S:[x==`S`[-1]for x in`S`[::-1]+'~'].index(0)
```

48 bytes for string as input. [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#y7GN@Z@TmJuUkqgQbBVdYWsbHK1rGJuWX6RQoZCZpxAcbWUF5GurG6jH6mXmpaRWaBho/i8oyswrUcjRUDc0MlbX5ELmGqMIgLn/AQ)

```
lambda S:[x==S[-1]for x in S[::-1]+'~'].index(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/fc79ad57ba18c5c26e3ba6f50965bca5), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

---

**Golfed**

```cs
i=>{int a=i.Length-1,b=a;while(a-->0&&i[a]==i[b]);return b-a;}
```

---

**Ungolfed**

```cs
i => {
    int a = i.Length - 1,
        b = a;

    while( a-- > 0 && i[ a ] == i[ b ] );

    return b - a;
}
```

---

**Ungolfed readable**

```cs
i => {
    int a = i.Length - 1, // Store the length of the input
        b = a ;           // Get the position of the last char

    // Cycle through the string from the right to the left
    //   while the current char is equal to the last char
    while( a-- > 0 && i[ a ] == i[ b ] );

    // Return the difference between the last position
    //   and the last occurrence of the same char
    return b - a;
}
```

---

**Full code**

```cs
using System;

namespace Namespace {
   class Program {
      static void Main( String[] args ) {
         Func<String, Int32> f = i => {
            int a = i.Length - 1, b = a;
            while( a-- > 0 && i[ a ] == i[ b ] );
            return b - a;
         };

         List<String>
            testCases = new List<String>() {
               "14892093",
               "12344444",
               "112311",
               "888888",
               "135866667"
            };

         foreach( String testCase in testCases ) {
            Console.WriteLine( $" Input: {testCase}\nOutput: {f( testCase )}\n" );
         }

         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

---

**Releases**

- **v1.1** - `- 1 byte`  - Thanks to [Kevin's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114146/get-your-dubs-together/114188#comment278413_114188) comment.
- **v1.0** -  `63 bytes` - Initial solution.

---

**Notes**

Nothing to add

Comment: +1 You can golf it by 1 byte, though. Like this: [`i=>{int a=i.Length-1,b=a;while(a-->0&&i[a]==i[b]);return b-a;}`](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-core#bZFNT8JAEIbv/IpJY0ib0IZSVLC2FxKNCUYjBw/IYSlDmaRsze5UYkh/Oy5USlGey2bnnX3nYwtNMoXJt2Zch62icfNGeZZhwpRL7T2iREVJ2GoBQJIJreFV5akSa9juQwbNgimBr5wW8CxI2jBhZeymMxAq1eDUmYaHQib3ld6BJ8lBL4YlRLCjKN6SZBAReWOUKa9cvzOPRLhZUYa2cN24227TVMyiiKbzmRMq5EJJmLsiLHdVgxVj0vxbIz5FDYyaR0KjNgUlbs4S7bM2Kyy/Pxj2usPA6vyXekF/zyXJaL5/QRgcuPQiuB7cGG6tM6lsTrXMFYpkddxuPQyQbAz2d4qR@cQ8Q@9dEeOYJNpwZZnFfxZ8B9vju/JDvhRcxZb2ydoxggVOeLIsGx0dvd9QLA7WdWK5P8vdDw)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Luis*

```
&Y'O)
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=%26Y%27O%29&inputs=%2712344444%27&version=19.8.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as a string
&Y'     % Perform run-length encoding on the string but keep only the second output
        % Which is the number of successive times an element appeared
O)      % Grab the last element from this array
        % Implicitly display
```

Comment: I had forgotten that `&` did that to `Y'`:-D Why not take input as a string enclosed in quotes and get rid of `j`?

Comment: @LuisMendo I wasn't sure if I could do that since the challenge explicitly said that input was an "integer"

Comment: I assumed so from [Martin's comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114146/get-your-dubs-together/114194?noredirect=1#comment278296_114146) and from the default rules, which allow that. But I'm not really sure

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah ok didn't see his comment. Will update!

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 91 bytes

```
@set s=-%1
@set n=1
:l
@if %s:~-2,1%==%s:~-1% set s=%s:~,-1%&set/an+=1&goto l
@echo %n%
```

The `-` prevents the test from running off the start of the string.

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 41 Bytes

```
for($n="$args";$n[-1]-eq$n[-++$a]){};$a-1
```

straightforward loop backwards until a char doesn't match the last char in the string, return the index of that char -1.

-3 thanks to @AdmBorkBork - using a for loop instead of a while.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

```
f=(n,p)=>n%10-p?0:1+f(n/10|0,n%10)
```

Not shorter than the regex solution.

Recursive function which evaluates the digits from right-to-left, stopping when a different digit is encountered. The result is the number of iterations. `p` is `undefined` on the first iteration, which means `n%10-p` returns `NaN` (falsy). After that, `p` equals the previous digit with `n%10`. When the current digit (`n%10`) and the previous (`p`) are different, the loop ends.

Answer (score 3):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 12 bytes

```
{count|tail}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#RYvBDoIwDIbP61M0PUGi0TLUccAnISELbAmJbgbmCfDV5/Ag36Hp/3/tUw8OZxC2buLc@bcLS9DDY43C@hGDmULb6clg70GIPX5qpMbRAYlSn/3FiSjHBW22zdc4uLC7dIzHO6anNgfRe2dgjVyqqjhXEriQ5QZw2phB/QCWF3VN3L4)

This is an anonymous function that expects that each character of the input string is pushed to the stream (I think this is valid in spirit of [a recent meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/when-to-allow-flexible-input-output)).

It uses two builtins: `count` and `tail`:

1. `count` reads values from the stream and pushes the number of consecutive elements to the stream.
2. `tail` returns the last value in the stream.

Answer (score 3):

### T-SQL, <strike>238</strike> 214 Bytes

```
declare @ varchar(max) = '' declare @i int=0, @e int=0, @n int=right(@,1), @m int while (@i<=len(@)) begin set @m=(substring(@,len(@)-@i,1)) if (@n=@m) set @e=@e+1 else if (@i=0) set @e=1 set @i=@i+1 end select @e
```

Or:

```
declare @ varchar(max) = '12345678999999'
declare 
    @i int = 0,
    @e int = 0,
    @n int = right(@,1),
    @m int

while (@i <= len(@))
begin
    set @m = (substring(@,len(@)-@i,1))
    if (@n = @m) set @e = @e + 1
    else
    if (@i) = 0 set @e = 1
    set @i = @i + 1
end
select @e
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>33</s> 30 bytes

*Thanks to Greg Martin for saving 3 bytes.*

```
Tr[1^Last@Split@Characters@#]&
```

Takes input as a string.

Gets the decimal digits (in the form of characters), splits them into runs of identical elements, gets the last run and computes the length with the standard trick of taking the sum of the vector `1^list`.

Comment: `Characters` instead of `IntegerDigits`?

Comment: @GregMartin Ah yeah, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: You still don't beat [that other shrewd Mathematica golfer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114159/56178) for this question ;)

Comment: @GregMartin What a shame. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, 78 bytes

```
int c(int n){return(""+n).length()-(""+n).replaceAll("(.)\\1*$","").length();}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#fY1LDoIwEED3nGLSuGj9NPJRIaw8gCuW4qLWBpuUQspgYghnR1ASd7zFJJN5eSONaBq4dB5AgwK1hEFbBEmnaVnnFLbOUkI2lnGjbIFPynbz7lRthFRnYyihnOW5v16RLSF/M@0HgLq9mzE891@VfkAptKUZOm2L602w6T1A9m5QlbxqkdfjBY2lkvpRnAT7JGQsXZCCMJpYlkbL9xeV@MtyJTzEx5HTz@q9fvgA)

I tried some things using recursion or a loop, but both ended up above 100 bytes..

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 27 bytes

```
f=n=>n%100%11?1:1+f(n/10|0)
```

Maybe not shorter than the regex-based solution, but I couldn't resist writing a solution entirely based on arithmetic. The technique is to repeatedly take `n % 100 % 11` and divide by 10 until the result is non-zero, then count the iterations. This works because if the last two digits are the same, `n % 100 % 11` will be `0`.

Comment: Ah, you finished just before me haha! I'm not sure whether to post another answer, since they will most likely converge after golfing, but here's my solution using 34 bytes: `f=(n,p)=>n%10-p?0:1+f(n/10|0,n%10)`

Comment: @user81655 That's great, feel free to post it. I don't think mine will converge down to that without a complete makeover, and of course now that I've seen yours that won't happen ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 - <del>50</del> 44 bytes

Full program (in Python 3, `input()` returns a string, no matter the input):

```python
g=input();print(len(g)-len(g.rstrip(g[-1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 34 bytes

```bash
sed s/.*[^${1: -1}].//<<<x$1|wc -c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@cmqJQrK@nFR2nUm1opaBrWBurp69vY2NToWJYU56soJv8//9/YzAAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 41 bytes

```c
f(x){return x&&x%10-x/10%10?1:f(x/10)+1;}
```

There are already 2 other C solutions, but they both depend on loops. This uses recursion. If the last 2 digits are different then it's 1, otherwise you do 1+ the number of consecutive digits of the number with the last digit removed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#@5@mUaFZXZRaUlqUp1ChplahamigW6FvaACk7Q2tgLJAtqa2oXXtf@XMvOSc0pRUm@KSlMx8vQw7rsy8EoXcxMw8Dc1qLs6CIiA3TUNJNSUmT0knTcPQxMLSyMDSWFPTGoukkbEJCGCXBMoaGmKVsgAD7LqMTS3MgMAcLAv1kYE1V@1/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)=sum[1|all(==h)t]+f t
f _=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mkWFVomlbXJobbViTmJOjYWuboVkSq52mUMKVphBva/A/R8FWIdrQxMLSyMDSWEfB0MjYBASALCDT0FBHwQIMgHxjUwszIDCP5cpNzMwDastNLPBVKCjKzCtRUAFxFNKgdHFGfrlCzn8A)

Takes string input. Repeatedly cuts off the first character, and adds 1 if all characters in the suffix are equal to the first one.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 35 bytes

```
rle(rev(charToRaw(scan(,''))))$l[1]
```

Brief explanation

```
                  scan(,'')         # get input as a string
        charToRaw(         )        # convert to a vector of raws (splits the string)
    rev(                    )       # reverse the vector
rle(                         )$l[1] # the first length from run length encoding
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 19 bytes

```
01g3j@.$~:01p-!j$1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@29gmG6c5aCnUmdlYFigq5ilYqj9/7@hiYWlkYGlMRD8BwA)

This could be made shorter if I managed to only use the stack.

How it works:

```
01g3j@.$~:01p-!j$1+
01g                 ; Get the stored value (default: 32)                 ;
   3j               ; Skip to the ~                                      ;
        ~           ; Get the next character of input                    ;
         :01p       ; Overwrite the stored value with the new char       ;
             -!     ; Compare the old value and the new                  ;
               j$   ; Skip the $ when equal, else pop the counter        ;
                 1+ ; Increment the counter                              ;

; When the input runs out, ~ reflects the IP and we run: ;
   @.$
     $              ; Pop the extraneous value (the stored value) ;
   @.               ; Print the number and exit                   ;
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ŒrṪṪ
```

Takes input as a string, returns a number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390UtHDnauA6P///0qGRsYmpmbmFiCgBAA)

Relatively simply, `Œr` Run-length encodes the input, `Ṫ` pushes the last pair, then `Ṫ` pushes its second item. Which thus gives us the length of consecutive digits at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 48 bytes

`#(-> (partition-by identity (str %)) last count)`

Usage: `(#(-> (partition-by identity (str %)) last count) 123455)`

`=> 2`

Ungolfed:

```
(defn count-digits [n]
                  (-> (partition-by identity (str n))
                      last
                      count))
```

## Common Lisp, 82 bytes

`(defun c (n) (if (eq (mod n 10) (floor (mod n 100) 10)) (+ 1 (c (floor n 10))) 1))`

Ungolfed:

```
(defun c (n)
  (if (eq (mod n 10)
          (floor (mod n 100) 10))
      (+ 1 (c (floor n 10))) 1))
```

Comment: Welcome To PPCG! Wonderful first post, It looks like you have the basics of formatting down, just note that in the future you an make multiple answers if you use multiple languages (good for getting more rep :) )

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `l`, 2 bytes

```
Ġt
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=l&code=%C4%A0t&inputs=12344444&header=&footer=)

> need to get this to 2 bytes somehow – Razetime

### Explained

```
Ġt
Ġ    # Group the integer into consecutive chunks
 t   # Take the tail of that list
     # The `-l` flag prints the length of TOS
```

Comment: need to get this to 2 bytes somehow

Answer (score 2):

### ARM Thumb-2 (no divide instruction/libgcc), 38 bytes

Raw machine code:

```
b530 2400 250a 3401 2200 280a d302 3201
380a e7fa 0001 0010 2d0a bf08 460d 428d
d0f1 1e60 bd30
```

Uncommented asm:

```armasm
        .text
        .arch armv6t2
        .globl dubs
        .thumb
        .thumb_func
dubs:
        push    {r4, r5, lr}
        movs    r4, #0
        movs    r5, #10
.Lloop:
        adds    r4, #1
        movs    r2, #0
.Ldivloop:
        cmp     r0, #10
        blo     .Ldivloop_end
        adds    r2, #1
        subs    r0, #10
        b       .Ldivloop
.Ldivloop_end:
        movs    r1, r0
        movs    r0, r2
        cmp     r5, #10
        it      eq
        moveq   r5, r1
        cmp     r5, r1
        beq     .Lloop
        subs    r0, r4, #1
        pop     {r4, r5, pc}
```

#### Explanation

C function signature:

```c
// Assume: post_id != 0
uint32_t dubs(uint32_t post_id);
```

First, push registers and set up our dubs counter in r4:

```armasm
dubs:
        push    {r4, r5, lr}
        movs    r4, #0
```

Now, in order to reuse the loop, we use a "magic" value of 10 for the last digit in r5, and set it at the end of the loop.

```armasm
        movs    r5, #10
```

Begin the count by incrementing the dubs counter:

```armasm
.Lloop:
        adds    r4, #1
```

Now, we start our divmod loop to divide the ID by 10 and get the remainder.

The divided ID will be in `r2` and the remainder will be in `r0`.

```armasm
        movs    r2, #0
.Ldivloop:
        cmp     r0, #10
        blo     .Ldivloop_end
        adds    r2, #1
        subs    r0, #10
        b       .Ldivloop
```

That is basically this in C:

```c
uint32_t quotient = 0;
while (dividend >= 10) {
    ++quotient;
    dividend -= 10;
}
uint32_t remainder = dividend;
```

This could probably be optimized. We ended up with the registers in the wrong spot, so we have to move things around. Specifically, we want the remainder in `r1` and the divided ID in `r0`.

The biggest problem is dealing with `movs` either clobbering the flags or requiring hi registers. If it didn't do that, I would put it after the `cmp`.

```armasm
.Ldivloop_end:
        movs    r1, r0
        movs    r0, r2
```

Now, we check for that magic number and set the lowest digit to that.

```armasm
        cmp     r5, #10
        it      eq
        moveq   r5, r1
```

Now, check if the new remainder in r1 and loop if it is the same as the last digit.

```armasm
        cmp     r5, r1
        beq     .Lloop
```

Move the dubs count into the return register and return. We are actually one too high so we have to correct it.

```armasm
        subs    r0, r4, #1
        pop     {r4, r5, pc}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>62</s> 55 bytes

```
i,j;f(n){for(i=0,j=n%10;++i;n/=10)if(j-n%10)return--i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#VYjBCsMgEAXvfoUEAi5RqjFtDeKf9FJohRW6LZKeQr7dGnPqwIM3U1AmHwXBGt9ZYNAyBeqN9sOAnk7BaMAoktob5OfyzaQU@q0gLfx1RxLAVsYrn1xTFF3/uNH/OsmjMJObRz1baDLaaeeQasa06xpHtWd3qVwBPNvKDw)

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 50 bytes

```
arg ''-1 # 1 n
say length(n)-length(strip(n,T,#))
```

Parse argument with empty string, causing parsing cursor to move to end of argument, then left one step, put remainder (one character) of argument in `#` variable, move to first character and put first word of argument in `n` variable.

Strip trailing characters equivalent to `#` from `n` and compare length to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>28</s> 22 bytes

```
->s{s[/(.)\1*$/].size}
```

Anonymous function that takes the number as a string.

Comment: I believe you can get the match of a regex in Ruby like `s[/(.)\1*$/]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 30 bytes

```matlab
@(s)find(flip(diff([0 +s])),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUayZlpmXopGWk1mgkZKZlqYRbaCgXRyrqaljqPk/TcFWITGv2JorTUPd0MTC0sjA0lhdE8wzMjYBASgPyDU0hLAtwAAqbmxqYQYE5uqa/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

```
f=(n,i=1)=>(a=[...n]).pop()==a[a.length-1]?f(a,i+1):i
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 bytes

```
¬â l ¥1?Ul :Uw ¬b@X¦UgJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@39ozeFFCjkKh5Ya2ofmKFiFliscWpPkEHFoWWi61///SoZGxiYgoAQA)

#### Explanation:

```
¬â l ¥1?Ul :Uw ¬b@X¦UgJ
¬                         // Split the input into an array of chars
 â                        // Return all unique permutations
   l ¥1                   // Check if the length is equal to 1
       ?                  // If yes, return: 
        Ul                //   The length of the input
            :             // Else, return:
             Uw           //   The input, reversed
                ¬         //   Split into an array of chars
                  @       //   Iterate through, where X is the iterative item
                 b        //   Return the first index where:
                   X¦     //     X != 
                     UgJ  //     The last char in the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 36 bytes

### Without import solution (39 bytes)

```
f n=length.takeWhile(==last n)$reverse n
```

<s>Note that a pointfree solution is longer (and less understandable):</s> EDIT: since anonymous functions are allowed, let's shave off two bytes which brings us to 39 (still longer than 36):

```
(length.).takeWhile.(==).last<*>reverse
```

### With import solution (36 bytes, 19 without import)

```
import Data.List
f=length.last.group
```

Run like `f "2394398222222"` either way

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93, 45 bytes

```
<_v#`0:~
pv>$00p110
p>00g-#v_10g1+10
  @.g01<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@28TX6acYGBVx1VQZqdiYFBgaGjAVWBnYJCuq1wWb2iQbqgNFFBQcNBLNzC0@f/f0MjYBAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Åγθ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5zed2/P9vaGxsbGFkBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w63nNp/b8V/nf7ShiYWlkYGlsY6hkbEJCOgYAlmGhjoWYKBjaGxqYQYE5kCWsbGFkVEsAA).

Or alternatively:

```
γθg
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZzO9L//zc0Nja2MDICAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c5vP7Uj/r/M/2tDEwtLIwNJYx9DI2AQEdAyBLENDHQsw0DE0NrUwAwJzIMvY2MLIKBYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åγ   # Run-length decode the (implicit) input-integer
     #  i.e. 1333822 → [1,3,1,2]
  θ  # Pop and push the last item
     #  → 2
     # (which is output implicitly as result)

γ    # Split the (implicit) input-integer into parts of subsequent equal digits
     #  i.e. 1333822 → [1,333,8,22]
 θ   # Pop and push the last item
     #  → 22
  g  # Pop and push its length
     #  → 2
     # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
her9
```

Kinda surprised this hasn't been posted yet.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyO1yPL/fyVDI2MTEFACAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 16 bytes

Input is STDIN. Subtracts the position of the start of the dubs sequence from the length of the string (technically, the position of the end of the string).

```ruby
p~/$/-~/(.)\1*$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6BOX0Vft05fQ08zxlBLRf//f0MTC0sjA0tjLkMjYxMQ4DIEsgwNuSzAgMvQ2NTCDAjM/@UXlGTm5xX/183LAQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì òÎÌÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7CDyzszK&input=MTIzNDU1NQ) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7CDyzszK&input=WwoxMjM0NTU1CjE0ODkyMDkzCjEyMzQ0NDQ0CjExMjMxMQo4ODg4ODgKMTM1ODY2NjY3Cl0tbVI)

```
ì òÎÌÊ     :Implicit input of integer
ì          :To digit array
  ò        :Partition between truthy pairs
   Î       :   Sign of difference
    Ì      :Last element
     Ê     :Length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
⊃⍸⌽1,2≠/⍞
```

`⍞` input as a string

`1,2≠/` 1 concatenated with n-wise reduction with ≠, boolean mask of the starts of sections

`⌽` reverse

`⊃⍸` index of the first 1

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97f@jruZHvTse9ew11DF61LlA/1HvPJDE/zQuQxMLSyMDS2MuINPI2AQEQEwg29AQyLAAA5CIsamFGRCYKwAA)

Comment: @Razetime true, edited

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
{+/&\|x=*|x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWltfLaamwlarpqL2f5q6iqGJhaWRgaWxgqGRsQkIKBgCWYaGChZgoGBobGphBgTm/wE)

Takes input as a string.

- `x=*|x` compare each digit to the last digit of the input
- `&\|` "turn off" `1b`s occurring after first `0b`, e.g. `&\|110011b` => `110000b`
- `+/` take sum

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
E:GH
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=E%3AGH&i=14892093%0A12344444%0A112311%0A888888%0A135866667&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

### x86_64 machine code, 24 bytes

Could probably be golfed a bit further.

Input and output is through rax as integers.

```
00000000  6a 0a 5d 31 f6 31 d2 f7  f5 89 d3 ff c6 31 d2 f7  |j.]1.1.......1..|
00000010  f5 39 d3 74 f6 89 f0 c3                           |.9.t....|
```

Disassembly (with explanation):

```
dubs:
  6a 0a                 push   0xa
  5d                    pop    rbp      ; set rbp to 10 (for divison)
  31 f6                 xor    esi,esi  ; zero counter
  31 d2                 xor    edx,edx  ; zero upper dividend
  f7 f5                 div    ebp      ; initial divide (can this be golfed into the other divide?)
  89 d3                 mov    ebx,edx  ; set ebx (repeating digit)
loop:
  ff c6                 inc    esi      ; inc counter
  31 d2                 xor    edx,edx  ; zero upper dividend (gets filled with remainder)
  f7 f5                 div    ebp      ; divide
  39 d3                 cmp    ebx,edx  ; compare repeating digit with digit 'popped'
  74 f6                 jz     loop     ; if equal keep looping
  89 f0                 mov    eax,esi  ; move counter to eax for output
  c3                    ret
```

Full program source to run subroutine:

```
; nasm -felf64 -odubs.o dubs.asm
; ld -odubs dubs.o
; ./dubs; echo $?

bits 64

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 12344444
    call dubs
    
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rax, 60
    syscall ; exit with return val as exit code
    
dubs:
    push 10
    pop rbp
    xor esi, esi
    xor edx, edx
    div ebp ; eax quot edx rem
    mov ebx, edx
loop:
    inc esi
    xor edx, edx
    div ebp ; eax quot edx rem
    cmp ebx, edx
    jz loop
    mov eax, esi
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ŒɠṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJMLHu5c9f9w@6OmNf//GxoZm5iamuoogBg6ChZgAAA)

Well, there’s a 5 byte and a 4 byte Jelly answer, so might as well go for 3 bytes

### How it works

```
ŒɠṪ - Main link. Takes l on the left as a list of digits
Œɠ  - Group adjacent equal values in l and get the lengths of each
  Ṫ - Get the last one
```

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 44 bytes

```
{for(d=$1%10;$1%10~d;k++)$1=($1-d)/10;$1=k}1
```

This piece of code uses math, so should work only with numbers.

```
{
for(             # $1 is the input, but will be modified during the code.
    d=$1%10;     # before the loop, records the last digit of $1 to _d_,
    $1%10~d;     # and stops if the last digit of $1 is different from _d_.
    k++          # increments 1 to _k_ after each loop.
   )
   $1=($1-d)/10; # removes the last digit of $1 and divides by 10.
                 # this uses less bytes than int($1/10).

$1=k             # after the end of the looping, assigns the count variable _k_
                 # to $1, which will become the output.
}
1                # prints $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPFVsVQ1dDAGkzWpVhna2trqhjaaqgY6qZo6oMlbLNrDf//NzQyNgEBAA)

---

## AWK, 44 bytes

```
{for(i=n=split($1,a,e);a[i--]~a[n];)$1=n-i}1
```

This code treats the input as string. Works with all kinds of characters.

```
{
for(
    i=n=split($1,a,e); # splits the input to the _a_ array,
                       # using the _e_ empty variable as flag (i.e, a null character)
                       # also sets the number of elements of the array
                       # to the _i_ and _n_ variables

    a[i--]~a[n];       # loops while the _i_ and _n_ elements are equal
                       # this also decrements _i_ by 1 after the evaluation
   )
     $1=n-i            # during each loop, sets the output to n-i
}
1                      # prints $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPTNs@2uCAns0RDxVAnUSdV0zoxOlNXN7YuMTov1lpTxdA2Tzez1vD/f0MjYxMQAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `tL`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0UomPUuyCpaUlaboWi44sXFKclFwM5S5YZmhoZGxoCOEBAA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġtl
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS44sLMlZUpyUXAwVWLDM0NDI2NAQwgMA)

##### Explanation

```python
     # Implicit input
ġ    # Group consecutive digits together
 t   # Get the last item (also done by t flag)
  l  # And push the length (also done by L flag)
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 18 bytes

```
{m/(.)$0*$/.chars}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZLCoAgFAXQrVxEohqkL/sYVFsJiaRBUthIorXb54zOsfitiS4gsRji5URaZFzmXBTzavx5x9MEMD5hGHFZ8OlmsLtHT5XuStkpUKmqD@gdEfQPpGrdvNoxPg)

`m/(.)$0*$/` applies a regex to the input argument that matches any number of the same trailing characters.  (In Raku, applying a regex to a number implicitly matches against its string representation.)  Then `.chars` counts how many characters there are in the match.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 36 bytes

```lua
s=...print(#s:match(~~(s%10)..'+$'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZPT6@gKDOvREO52Co3sSQ5Q6OuTqNY1dBAU09PXVtFXVPz////hkbGJiAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## **PHP 40chars**

(Does not take into account php tags)

```
strlen(preg_match('/(.)\1*$/',$argv[1]))
```

Comment: I think you mean `preg_match('/(.)\1*$/',$argv[1],$t);echo strlen($t[0]);` or as alternative `<?=strlen(preg_filter('/.*?((.)\2*)$/','\1',$argv[1]));`

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 49 bytes

```
i=>i.Reverse().TakeWhile(x=>x==i.Last()).Count();
```

[Try it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hI81cO)

**Full code**

```
  using System;
  using System.Linq;

  class Program
  {
      static void Main()
      {
          Func<string, int> func = i=>i.Reverse().TakeWhile(x=>x==i.Last()).Count();

          Console.WriteLine(func("14892093"));
          Console.WriteLine(func("12344444"));
          Console.WriteLine(func("112311"));
          Console.WriteLine(func("888888"));
          Console.WriteLine(func("135866667"));
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>64</s> 62 bytes

Golfed:

```
int w(int x){int r=1,d=x%10;while((x/=10)%10==d)r++;return r;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int w(int x)
{
    int r = 1, d = x % 10;
    while ((x /= 10) % 10 == d)
        r++;
    return r;
}
```

[Try it online](https://ideone.com/EHHxz7)

Answer (score 0):

## Vim - 39

```
ix^[Y$d?[^^R=@@[len(@@)-2]^M]^Mcc^R=len(@2)^M
```

(*^[*, *^M*s and *^R*s are one char each)

- insert non-number (for *88888* input), copy line, move to the end
- delete searching backwards for a char other then the last char
- replace line with length of deleted text

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
>:i.&1}.~:|.":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@29nlamnZlirV2dVo6dk9f8/Kl/B0MTC0sjA0pgLXdzI2AQEMMSBEoaG6KIWYICh1tjUwgwIzHFKoIEKAA)

It's fortunate that the challenge allows a REPL command. As a verb (function) it's 20 bytes:

```
3 :'>:i.&1}.~:|.":y'
```

For arbitrarily large integers, the literal must be suffixed by `x`.

#### Explained

Applied right to left, all monadic verbs:

- `":` Format - Stringifies its argument
- `|.` Reverse
- `~:` Nub sieve - Produces a boolean array of 1's each time a new item is introduced, 0 otherwise
- `}.` Behead - Removes first item of array
- `i.&1` Index of - Gets index of first `1`. `i.` is actually a dyadic verb, but `&1` ties right argument to `1`.
- `>:` Increment

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 72 chars

```
(lambda(i)(do((n i(floor n 10))(c 1(1+ c)))((/= 0(mod(mod n 100)11))c)))
```

Unoglfed

```
(lambda (i)
  (do ((n i (floor n 10))
       (c 1 (1+ c)))
      ((/= 0 (mod (mod n 100) 11)) c)))
```

Explanation

`(/= 0 (mod (mod n 100) 11))`

This checks to see if the last two digits of n are different- if n%100 is  not divisible by 11.

```
(do ((n i (floor n 10))
     (c 1 (1+ c)))
    (... c))
```

`do` is a powerful generic looping construct in lisp. Its first argument  is a list describing the looping variables. Each element is a list of (variable initial-value step-form) where step-form is evaluated each time through the loop to update that variable. The second argument is a test to perform to end the loop (the test I covered above) and a list of values to return after looping (in this case just `c`, which has been incrementing each time though the loop).

`(lambda (i) ...)`
Wraps the operation in an anonymous function that takes the number as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>22</del> <del>21</del> 20 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: d1ee 8a1c 8d38 8a05 fdf3 aef6 d191 052f  .....8........./
00000010: 0ecd 10c3                                ....
```

Build and test `DUBS.COM` with `xxd -R`.

**Unassembled listing:**

```
D1 EE       SHR  SI, 1              ; SI to command line tail (80H) 
8A 1C       MOV  BL, BYTE PTR[SI]   ; BX = input string length 
8D 38       LEA  DI, [BX][SI]       ; DI to end of string 
8A 05       MOV  AL, BYTE PTR[DI]   ; AL = last char
FD          STD                     ; set LODS to decrement 
F3 AE       REPZ SCASB              ; scan [DI] backwards until AL doesn't match
F6 D1       NOT  CL                 ; negate CL to get number of matches + 1
91          XCHG AX, CX             ; AL = CL 
05 2F0E     ADD  AX, 0E2FH          ; ASCII convert and adjust, BIOS tty function
CD 10       INT  10H                ; write number to console 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
```

A standalone PC DOS executable program.  Input via command line, output number to console.

**Notes:**

This takes advantage of a few "features" of PC DOS [register startup values](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181407/84624); specifically `BH = 0`, `CX = 00FFH` and `SI = 100H`.  `REPZ` decrements `CX` on every compare operation, so starting at `00FFH` will yield a negative count of reps.  It is off-by-one because `REPZ` decrements before comparison, so the first non-match still gets counted.  That number is ones-complimented and adjusted by 1 to get the count of matched digits.

Also, since `CH = 0` it's possible to combine `ADD AL, '0'-1` and `MOV AH, 0EH` into a single instruction `ADD AX, 0E2FH` to save 1 byte, since `AH` will be `0`.  Old-school [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) for you!

**I/O:**

[image]