# Build a Faulty XKCD Browser

Tags: code-golf, internet

### Challenge

Given the number of an XKCD comic, output the title text of that comic (the mouseover text).

However, the program must throw an error when given the numbers `859` or `404`.

### Rules

The number given will always be an existing comic (except `404`).

Your program must not throw an error for any other numbers than `859` or `404`.

For reference, comic [`404`](https://xkcd.com/404) does not exist and [`859`](https://xkcd.com/859/) is:

```
Brains aside, I wonder how many poorly-written xkcd.com-parsing scripts will break on this title (or ;;"''{<<[' this mouseover text."
```

Url shorteners are disallowed. You may use the internet to get the title text.

### Examples

```
Input > Output
1642 > "That last LinkedIn request set a new record for the most energetic physical event ever observed. Maybe we should respond." "Nah."
1385 > ::PLOOOOSH:: Looks like you won't be making it to Vinland today, Leaf Erikson.
1275 > If replacing all the '3's doesn't fix your code, remove the 4s, too, with 'ceiling(pi) / floor(pi) * pi * r^floor(pi)'. Mmm, floor pie.
1706 > Plus, now I know that I have risk factors for elbow dysplasia, heartworm, parvo, and mange.
```

### Bounty

I will award a bounty to the shortest answer which fails on comic 859 because it's poorly written instead of checking for the number.

Your program may break on other alt texts (such as 744) providing they have unmatched parentheses, quotation marks etc.

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is returning `null` valid as Error?

Comment: @RomanGräf Uhh yeah, I think it can be

Comment: Do we need to parse html entities like &#39;?

Comment: @thegreatemu Yes

Comment: Since there are other comics with script-breaking alt texts (see [744](https://xkcd.com/744)), is it okay if a program breaks on those too?

Comment: @totallyhuman You should've added a slightly-NSFW-warning to that :P

Comment: @totallyhuman Yes, that's fine

Comment: Contradiction in the challenge: "must not throw an error for any other numbers than `859` or `404`" and "may break on other alt texts".

Comment: @aschepler The latter is only for the bounty

Comment: @BetaDecay this suggests the bounty may be applied to an answer that is invalid, inviting invalid answers.

Comment: Or should the invalid code be included as an aside in a valid answer?

Comment: Isn't this likely to be akin unto a DDOS against the site?  And thus should be done with permission?

Comment: @Kzqai Good question, but I think you may be slightly underestimating how much traffic is involved in a DDOS, and also how much traffic xkcd.com already has. I wouldn't expect the traffic generated from answers here to be significant compared to either of those.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2) + [xkcd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xkcd),  55 bytes

[xkcd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xkcd) is a third-party Python package. In Python, there is a [package for everything](https://xkcd.com/353/)!

```python
lambda n:[xkcd.getComic(n).altText][n==859]
import xkcd
```

> For **404:** `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`
>
> For **859:** `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: The package was written before this challenge and wasn't written specifically *for* this challenge, it just ends up being ***highly*** appropriate.

Comment: Wow, Python just got more attractive!

Comment: @Nat [Come join Us!](https://xkcd.com/353/)

Comment: The [pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xkcd) says it's Python 2 compatible also, fwiw. Great find!

Comment: Coincidentally, python does indeed support `import`'ing `antigravity`.

Comment: Did Python just Mathematica this challenge?

Answer (score 21):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2) + [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), <s>104</s> <s>102</s> <s>95</s> 94 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer. -1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan.*

```python
lambda n:[get('http://xkcd.com/%d/info.0.json'%n).json()['alt']][n==859]
from requests import*
```

Obligatory:

```python
import antigravity
```

### Poorly written script, 98 bytes

So, writing poor scripts is actually hard to do intentionally... This also breaks on other comics because they contain quotes, not sure if that's okay.

```python
from requests import*
exec'print "%s"'%get('http://xkcd.com/%d/info.0.json'%input()).json()['alt']
```

Comment: I think you can remove `,a`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: You can change `n in[404,859]` to `n==859`, because the JSON decoder fails for `404` anyway.

Comment: @musicman523 Ninja'd you. ;)

Comment: @totallyhuman Ya got me ;)

Comment: ... `http://` can be used here too, I think.

Comment: how do you actually run this with a parameter?  Like, how do you run a nameless lambda?

Comment: @MrZander The first line is an anonymous lambda that can be assigned to a variable to be run. For example, both `f = lambda n: n * 2; print f(2)` or `(lambda n: n * 2)(2)` will print 4.

Comment: @totallyhuman Is it standard on codegolf.se that user input doesn't need to be counted towards total character count?

Comment: @MrZander Yes, it is standard, and unused function names do not add towards the score.

Comment: If you're willing to add 4 extra bytes, you can stop it from breaking on any comic with quotes: `from requests import*;exec'print """%s"""'%get('http://xkcd.com/%d/info.0.json'%input()).json()['alt']`

Answer (score 18):

## Python 2 + xkcd, 82 bytes

Poorly written script

```python
lambda n:eval("'''%s'''"%xkcd.getComic(n).altText.replace(';;',"'''"))
import xkcd
```

Appends and prepends `'''`, which, unless the text contains `'''`, will not break, even for other quotation marks. That is, except if the text contains `;;`, which gets replaced with `'''` (eliminating `re`). This only applies for `859`, and thus this code breaks on `859`. :P

Also, one should never `eval` random internet content, because if `xkcd.getComic(n).altText` somehow became `'''+__import__('os').system('rm -rf / --no-preserve-root')+'''`, it would cause many bad things to happen. Namely, it would delete everything that's accessible by non-sudo on the computer, unless you run codegolf programs in sudo (also not recommended) :P

Comment: Poorly written and fails for that test case, `859`? Someone is going to get a bounty, I suppose...

Comment: Ah the cringe for evaling random content from the internet - bravo! :P

Comment: @LukeBriggs It should theoretically be safe... I mean, my computer hasn't exploded (_yet_) so it should be fine, right? :P But alternatively you could use `__import__('ast').literal_eval` in place of `eval` if you really wanted :P

Comment: Does it break on 744?

Comment: @Draco18s It shouldn't, because the triple quotes don't care about the mismatched quotes, and there's no `;;`.

Comment: Noted. :) Was just curious.

Answer (score 12):

## [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language)/Mathematica, <s>118</s> 117 bytes

*saved a byte thanks to numbermanic*

```
If[ImportString[#,"HTML"]===#,#,$Failed]&@Import[StringTemplate["http://xkcd.com/``/info.0.json"]@#,"RawJSON"]@"alt"&
```

Explanation:

Use `StringTemplate`to form the URL from the input.

`Import[..., "RawJSON"]` imports the JSON object and parses it into an [`Assocation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).

Select the value for the key `"alt"`.

Take this result and try to interpret the string as HTML (`Import[#,"HTML"]`).  If this doesn't change anything pass the result through, if it does return `$Failed`.  This catches 859 because

```
ImportString[
 "Brains aside, I wonder how many poorly-written xkcd.com-parsing 
  scripts will break on this title (or ;;\"''{<<[' this mouseover text.\"","HTML"]
```

results in:

```
Brains aside, I wonder how many poorly-written xkcd.com-parsing 
scripts will break on this title (or ;;"''{
```

404 fails because

```
If[
 ImportString[$Failed["alt"], "HTML"] === $Failed["alt"], 
 $Failed["alt"],
 $Failed]
```

results in `$Failed`.

Comment: What version are you using? I get `The Import element "RawJSON" is not present when importing as JSON` on 10.0.1.

Comment: @totallyhuman Well it probably doesn't need to check for 859. (See the bounty condition in the question)

Comment: @JulianWolf I am using 11.1.0. I think "RawJSON" support was added in 10.2.

Comment: @totallyhuman It doesn't do an explicit check, but that's what the `ImportString[#,"HTML"]` bit is all about.

Comment: Could you save a byte by using `@"alt"` at the end?

Comment: @numbermaniac Indeed I can.  Can't believe I missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

### Java 8, <s>255</s> 176 bytes

Thanks to @OlivierGrégoire for making me feel like an idiot and 79 bytes off. ;)

```
i->new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("http://xkcd.com/"+i+"/info.0.json").openStream()).useDelimiter("\\a").next().replaceFirst(".*\"alt\": \"","").replaceFirst("\".*","")
```

<s>This feels way too heavy...</s> Still heavy, but "okay" for java...

#### Explanation:

- `i->{...}` Lambda that works like `String <name>(int i) throws Exception`
- `new java.util.Scanner(...).setDelimiter("\\a").next()` read everything from the given `InputStream`

  - `new java.net.URL("http://xkcd.com/"+i+"/info.0.json").openStream()` this creates an `InputStream` which references the response body of `http://xkcd.com/{comic_id}/info.0.json` which is the info page of the desired comic
  - `replaceFirst(".*\"alt\": \"","").replaceFirst("\".*","")` Removes everything except for the alt text (till the first double quote)
- implicit return

### Alternate shorter approach, Java + json.org, 150

```
i->i==859?new Long(""):new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(new java.net.URL("http://xkcd.com/"+i+"/info.0.json").openStream())).get("alt")
```

This is not my solution so I don't want to post this as the first. All the credits belong to @OlivierGrégoire.

Comment: [Your imports are missing!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8782/16236). Also, there's nearly zero attempt to golf this answer...

Comment: Added. Just under 2^8. At least the size of my programm fits in one byte :)

Comment: `i->new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("http://xkcd.com/"+i+"/info.0.json").openStream()).useDelimiter("\\a").next().replaceFirst(".*\"alt\": \"","").replaceFirst("\".*","")` (176 bytes, careful to the SO's comment cutter characters) And I just barely golfed anything here.

Comment: Oh! I thought `Scanner#useDelimiter` returns void... Better read the docs next time ;)

Comment: I just noticed you can create your own `Function` class that allows you to throw Exception.. Today's​ not my day.

Comment: If you use the basic, official JSON library (need to change the title to "Java + JSON.org"), you can get it down to 131 bytes: `i->new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(new java.net.URL("http://xkcd.com/"+i+"/info.0.json").openStream())).get("alt")`

Comment: I think that one doesn't fail on `#859`.. But wait! There is a java json default library? I always used `gson`...

Comment: It is not required to fail on 859! It says that we may not throw errors on numbers other than 404 and 859! Meaning, we *may* but *aren't forced* to throw errors on those numbers.

Comment: "However, the program must throw an error when given the numbers `859` or `404`." ~Second paragraph of ##Challenge

Comment: Then be creative! `i->i==859?new Long(""):new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(new java.net.URL("http://xkcd.com/"+i+"/info.0.json").openStream())).get("alt")` for 150 bytes.

Comment: I think that is your own solution and not mine anymore. if you still want me to include it I'll do that :)

Comment: It's your call: I won't post it as mine. My goal on this website is to make my brain work, not to gain rep.

Comment: But still you've done very well... I should also get my brain working (or go to bed, I've slept too few yesterday)

Comment: By the way, there is no official Java Json library (there's a Java EE spec, and Jackson is its reference implementation). The library I mentioned is the library done by the guys who made the Json spec (so it's "official" by Json.org, not by Java). You're free to use whatever library you want. I personally use Gson as well, but the byte-count is unreasonable for golfing.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/) + [xkcd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xkcd), 54 bytes

```python
import xkcd
lambda n:xkcd.getComic(*{n}-{859}).altText
```

#### Verification

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.tracebacklimit = 0
>>>
>>> import xkcd
>>> f = lambda n:xkcd.getComic(*{n}-{859}).altText
>>>
>>> print f(149)
Proper User Policy apparently means Simon Says.
>>>
>>> f(404)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>>>
>>> f(859)
TypeError: getComic() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: I've only just noticed this. Nice golf!

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>89</s> <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```
<?=($a=$argv[1])==859?_:@json_decode(file("http://xkcd.com/$a/info.0.json")[0])->alt;
```

Returns null for 404 and 859

Save as xkcd.php and run with the comic number...

```
$ php xkcd.php 386
```

Comment: use `$argn`instead of `$argv[1]` , `_` instead of `NULL`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Thanks! I didn't know about _. $argn doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php `$argn` is available if you run PHP from the command Line with the `-R` or the `-F` option

Comment: `_` is not equivalent to `NULL` in PHP. This script throws an error about `_` being an undefined constant.

Comment: @Andy If a Notice is not allowed `""` is a better alternative as `NULL` Jared here is an example for `$argn` https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114146/get-your-dubs-together/114161#114161

Comment: @JörgHülsermann ah, I didn't realise you meant use it as an arbitrary character to throw a notice :)

Comment: Didn't know he was serving JSON ... nice work!

Comment: Per the other PHP answer, you can save one byte by replacing "https" with "http".

Answer (score 7):

## Bash + curl + jq: <s>73</s> 66 bytes

Shortest answer that doesn't use an xkcd-specific library. jq is a tool for manipulating json objects in the shell, and it comes complete with a parsing language to do that.

<s>`curl -Ls xkcd.com/$1/info.0.json|jq -r 'if.num==859then.num.a else.alt end'`</s>

`curl -Ls xkcd.com/$1/info.0.json|jq -r '(.num!=859//.[9]|not)//.alt'`

Expansion below:

`curl -Ls` - Query, but feel free to redirect (in this case to the https site) and give no unrelated output.

`xkcd.com/$1/info.0.json` - Shamelessly stolen from another answer.

`|jq -r` - Run `jq` in "raw output" mode on the following command.

`if
    .num == 859
then
    .num.a # This fails because you can't get the key 'a' from a property that's an integer
else
    .alt # And this pulls out the 'alt' key from our object.
end`

Now the script has been re-worked to use `//` which is the equivalent of `a or b` in python, and we use a `|not` to make any true value be considered false, so the second `//` can print `.alt`

Answer (score 5):

## PHP 5.3, <s>280</s> <s>268</s> <s>262</s> <s>261</s> 180 bytes

---

*1. Saved 11 thanks to some of Roman Gräf's suggestions*
*2. Saved 1 byte by using http link instead of https*
*3. Saved another 6 bytes thanks to Kevin_Kinsay*
*4. Saved another 1 byte with Andy's suggestion*
*5. A major revision:*

- suppressed errors with @ instead of changing `libxml_use_internal_errors`
- used `implode(0,file(""))` instead of `file_get_contents("")` (2 bytes)
- moved the `$x` definition inside the `if`
- Using `throw 0` instead of actually throwing an exception (it crashes the program)
- with the `@` I now can omit the `comicLink` replace.

---

My first try on golfing.

The DOMDocument breaks when encounters dobule ID comicLinks so I had to remove these. There's probably a nicer way of doing that.

Crashes when trying to get no. 859 ;)

```
<?php if(($x=$argv[1])==859)throw 0;$a=new DOMDocument;$b=@$a->loadHTML(implode(0,file("http://xkcd.com/$x")));echo $a->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(1)->getAttribute('title');
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think you can remove the test whether `$x==404` because the other code will fail on the 404 response... Also you can replace `throw new Exception` by a `die` call and remove the brackets around `throw new Exception("")`/`die` because it is only a single statement

Comment: Thanks!
I wasn't sure if die() would count as "throw an error" ;)

Comment: Use "1" instead of 'true' on libxml_use_internal_errors. You can probably pass 0 to the Exception and save one quote equivalent.  Closing ?> should be optional.

Comment: Variables are interpolated inside double quotes, so `"http://xkcd.com/".$x` can become `"http://xkcd.com/$x"` saving one byte :)

Comment: BTW, +1 for using "proper" parsing technique (XML parser) as opposed to my ugly regex hack ;)

Comment: ..Just managed to cut 81 bytes :D

Answer (score 5):

The Python one has already won, but regardless...

## bash + curl + sed; <strike>88</strike> ~91 <sup><sup><sup>heh</sup></sup></sup> bytes

```
printf "$(curl -s https://xkcd.com/2048/info.0.json|sed 's/.*"alt": "//;s/", "img":.*//')\n"
```

Yay for regex JSON parsing!

**EDIT** NoLongerBreathedIn noticed (648 days into the future!) that this failed on post 2048 because of an unexpected `\"` in that entry's JSON. The regex has been updated above; it used to be `sed 's/.*alt": "\([^"]\+\).*/\1/')`.

The `printf` wrapper neatly handles the fact that Unicode characters are represented in `\unnnn` notation:

```
$ printf "$(curl -s https://xkcd.com/1538/info.0.json | sed 's/.*"alt": "//;s/", "img":.*//')\n"
To me, trying to understand song lyrics feels like when I see text in a dream but it hอᵣd t₀ ᵣeₐd aกd  canٖt fཱྀcu༧༦࿐༄
```

### This fails with posts 404 and 859:

#### 404

```
$ printf "$(curl -s https://xkcd.com/404/info.0.json | sed 's/.*alt": "\([^"]\+\).*/\1/')\n"
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

#### 859

```
$ printf "$(curl -s https://xkcd.com/859/info.0.json | sed 's/.*alt": "\([^"]\+\).*/\1/')\n"
Brains aside, I wonder how many poorly-written xkcd.com-parsing scripts will break on this title (or ;;\n$
```

The `$` at the end of the output is my prompt, and the literally-printed `\n` immediately before it is part of the printf string.

I deliberately used `printf` because it would parse Unicode *and* fall over terribly on this specific post.

Comment: Also barfs on 2048. I think it barfs on double quotes?

Comment: Nice catch. Post updated. Looking at the `sed` bit, you can see it was looking for `alt": "` then reading until it found a `"`. Woops, apparently... (I wonder how many of these solutions would fail a unit test of 
*e̲͕̲̪v̲̺̗̱̬er̶͎y̦ ͖̙̝̦s҉̟̜i͓͜n̡g̸l͎̠̹̪͈͉͚͟e̩͙̙̣̲͕͘ ̴͎͉̳̮a̢͕l̯̦̮̥̺̱̤t̕ ͕̮̪̙̬̲̪͘t̰͙̘̪̼ͅex̺͕͍͔̠̮ͅt̪͔̀*? :P)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>115</s> 106 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to ovs. -1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan.*

Just thought I'd put a standard library answer out there.

```python
lambda n:[json.load(urllib.urlopen('http://xkcd.com/%d/info.0.json'%n))['alt']][n==859]
import urllib,json
```

Comment: `lambda n:[json.load(urllib.urlopen('https://xkcd.com/%d/info.0.json'%n))['alt']][n==859]` for -8 bytes.

Comment: Should work with `http://` too saving a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 160 bytes

```
<? preg_match_all('/(tle=\")(.+)(\")\sa/',join(0,file('http://xkcd.com/'.$argv[1])),$a);echo(strstr($c=$a[2][0],'Brains asid'))?$b:html_entity_decode($c,3);
```

Comment: Hang on ... this isn't to spec.  Fixing ...

Comment: Fixed.  Had to add about 50 bytes though ... :(

Comment: And a few more to handle the &#39; :( :(

Comment: Shaved 1 byte with "implode/file"...

Comment: Shaved 10 bytes on the regexp and by using join (alias to implode()), etc.

Comment: Nice job. You could probably reduce "Brains aside" to "Brains a"

Comment: you can remove 7 chars removing the echo and moving the $c assign inside the substr

Comment: Why check the substring instead of check the input?

Comment: @BetaDecay because not checking for the input number gives extra points

Comment: That's not what I meant. Your program should be poorly written: whether it be the unmatched parentheses, the semicolons or the unmatched quotation marks which break the program

Comment: @BetaDecay well, a script that depends on content looks poorly written to me. Any other title starting like that would break it.

Kevin_Kinsey you can replace ENT_QUOTES by its value=3

Comment: Thanks Einacio ... I was looking for that but couldn't figure it from the manual.

Comment: Ooh, I need to update it though ... the last version I wc'ed used something besides 'Brains aside' ... hopefully I can get back on this after work and the theatre tonight....

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>177</s> 175 bytes

```
p=(x)=>{eval(`console.log("${x.alt}")`)};f=(y)=>{var d=document,e=d.createElement("script");e.src=`//dynamic.xkcd.com/api-0/jsonp/comic/${y}?callback=p`;d.body.appendChild(e)}}
```

Paste this into your browser console, then execute `f(859)` or `f(404)` etc - those two should error in the console, despite not being hard coded, the others display.

First post in a while, sorry if it doesn't quite meet the rules...!

Comment: Use `x=>` instead of `(x)=>`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>110</s></sup> 73 bytes

```apl
{'('∊⎕←⍵.safe_title:-⍵⋄⍵.alt}⎕JSON∊⎕SH∊'curl -L xkcd.com/'⍞'/info.0.json'
```

-37 bytes from Adám.

### Explanation

```apl
⎕JSON∊⎕SH∊'curl -L xkcd.com/'⍞'/info.0.json'
                                     ⍝ Get the json data for the required page
                                     ⍝ Using ⎕SH to execute curl shell command
'('∊⎕←⍵.safe_title:                  ⍝ If the safe title does not contain a bracket,  
                    ⋄⍵.alt           ⍝ Print alt text
                  -⍵                 ⍝ Otherwise negate json data(Domain error)
```

Comment: It's does not match. I copied the wrong code. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 61: `(⎕JSON∊⎕SH'/859/'⎕R''∊'curl -L xkcd.com/'⍞'/info.0.json').alt`

Comment: Btw, you don't need Extended for this. And the TIO link can't work.

Comment: Could you update the explanation?

Comment: Sure, I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>129</s> 167 bytes

```
use LWP::Simple;use HTML::Entities;print decode_entities($1)if(get("http://www.xkcd.com/$ARGV[0]")=~m/text: ([^<]*)\}\}<\/div>/)
```

EDIT: Psyche it's actually

```
use LWP::Simple;use HTML::Entities;$x=$ARGV[0];if($x==404||$x==859){die}else{print decode_entities($1)if(get("http://www.xkcd.com/$x")=~m/text: ([^<]*)\}\}<\/div>/)}
```

Import HTML decoding and HTTP accessing, then print the group matching the (...) in

`{{Title text: (...)}}</div>`

(saving a bit by omitting `{{Title`  from the query)

For 404 and 859, death.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly handles 859"?

Comment: @BetaDecay It prints the actual alt-text

Comment: ***`the program must throw an error when given the numbers 859 or 404`***

Comment: What is "throw an error" defined as?

Comment: Nvm `die` is short enough

Comment: s/print/say/g also you can use -MModule

Answer (score 1):

## BASH, <strike>111</strike> 108 bytes

<strike>a=$(cat)
    curl -s https://xkcd.com/$a/ |grep -oP '(?<=Title text:)([^}}]*)'
    [ $a = 404 ] && echo "$a not found"</strike>

```
a=#;curl -s https://xkcd.com/$a/ |grep -oP '(?<=Title text:)([^}}]*)';[ $a = 404 ] && echo "$a not found"
```

To Run:
change # to number of comic. Run from command line.
Thanks @Ale for the suggestion!

Comment: Why reading from standard input using cat instead of just using $1 from the command line? It would save some bytes...

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>118</s> <s>96</s> 94 bytes

```
f=n=>fetch(`//xkcd.com/${n}/info.0.json`).then(x=>x.json()).then(y=>eval(`alert('${y.alt}')`))
```

You can paste that in your browser console and run `f(123)`. But do so on a page that is already on xkcd.com or else you'll see a CORS error.

For 404, it fails with:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

For 859, it fails with:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

*Update: the lastest version properly checks the alt text instead of checking for just 859 and shaves of another 2 bytes.*

Comment: Sadly, this fails on any titletext containing an apostrophe (e.g. 1084).